# Python win32com Excel CreatePivotChart - How to Specify Table

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pivot-table, win32com, pivot-chart

This is a follow up to this question: [Python win32com PivotCache.CreatePivotChart() error: 'Exception occurred'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953990/python-win32com-pivotcache-createpivotchart-error-exception-occurred)

I have 2 Pivot Tables on 1 sheet, and whenever I try to create a Pivot Chart for the Second Pivot Table, it always uses the First Pivot Table.

The previous question did not show how to specify what Table to use.

if I try this, code, it always uses the Table that is First
`chart = ws2.Shapes.AddChart2(276, xlAreaStacked)`

I recorded a excel macro and this is what it showed  `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet3!TorquePivotTable")`

However I'm not sure how to convert that line into something python likes, since there is a space between "SetSourceData Source:"

Answer (score 0):

ok, after about 3+ hours of  additional time messing with this,  turns out all you have to do is select a cell inside the Pivot Table you want to use, THEN add the chart....  so:

```
    ws2.Range('A13').Select()
    chart = ws2.Shapes.AddChart2(276, xlAreaStacked)
```